# Should I use methods or subclasses? If that makes sense

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, oop, sinemacula

### A Little Background...

I have an an object called `SineMacula` which houses many methods for creating form elements and making these form elements do things on a page.

Firstly, when the page loads, a method called `setFields()` is called which loops through all the fields on a page and sets them appropriately ***i.e. autocomplete, checkbox etc...***

The code for `setFields()` looks like this:

```
/**
 * Set Fields
 * This function will set all fields
 *
 * The options:
 * - fields: the fields selector to loop through
 *
 * @param object options The field options
 */
SineMacula.prototype.setFields = function (options){
    // Set the defaults for the fields
    var options = $.extend({
        fields: '.field', // Define the default field selector
    },options);
    // Loop through the fields and set the events
    $(options.fields).each(function(){
        // Set the field events
        SineMacula.setBlur($(this));        
        SineMacula.setFocus($(this));
        SineMacula.setToggleLabel($(this));
        // If the field is a checkbox then set it
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('checkbox')){
            SineMacula.setCheckbox($(this).parent());
        }
        // If the field is an autocomplete then set it
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('autocomplete')){
            SineMacula.setDropdown($(this).parent(),{source:$(this).attr('data-source')});
        }
        // etc...
    });
};
```

***Most of the code above can be ignored, but I have inserted all of it so that you can see exactly what I am doing.***

### My Question

I have quite a few methods of the `SineMacula` object such as `setCheckbox()`, `setDropdown()`...

What I would like to know is, should I be treating these methods as objects in themselves?

So should my code look like this instead:

```
if($(this).parent().hasClass('autocomplete')){
     new SineMacula.dropdown($(this).parent(),{source:$(this).attr('data-source')});
}
```

***Notice the `new` keyword before calling the `dropdown()` method.***

Is this a better method of working things? Will be use less memory etc?

Comment: Good question. I'd like to know the answer to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to create an instance of an object only to call the constructor and then throw the object away. By doing the work in the constructor you are just using it as a regular function, but with the overhead of creating an unused object.

(In fact you don't seem to use the SineMacula instance for anything either, other than as a namespace for the methods.)

Comment: There are lot more methods that go with the `SineMacula` object, this is just a snippet. The reason I thought I should create an object for the `dropdown()` method is that there are several methods within the `dropdown()` method. Is it still better to simply use it as a method instead of an object?

Comment: @BenCarey: Do you keep any state in the `SineMacula` object? Do you call any methods as instance methods (e.g. `this.setBlur(x);`) rather than static functions (e.g. `SineMacula.setBlur(x);`)? If you don't keep the `dropdown` object after you called the constructor, there is no reason to create the object. You can create an object inside the `dropdown` method if you want to keep state between methods during the work.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are saying, Where I define the `SineMacula()` class there is a method defined as `this.load()` and this is called at the beginning of my pages by calling `SineMacula.load(libraries)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @BenCarey: Do you create an instance of the object, and use that? E.g. `var s = new SineMacula(); s.load(); s.setFields();`

Comment: Yes I do create an instance :-)

Comment: @Ben: but why do you create an instance? it doesnt seem like you are tracking state or using it for anyting except a module namespace.

Comment: @prodigitalson by tracking state, do you mean something like `SineMacula(something).dropdown();`? You are right and I am starting to think whether it is necessary to have this object, take a look at my comment on Andres's answer and it might make more sense. Would like to hear your views on that. Effectively I am just following jQuery :-) But will change my method if it is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb a new object appears when you need to delegate some responsibility to it. So if you later do something like `sineMaculaInstance.setCheckboxValue(checkbox, true)` it definitely looks like that should be checkbox responsibility.
Another way of looking at it is to analize the SineMacula object by the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In short, if you can describe what your object does in one or two lines you are generally ok. If you have to write an entire paragraph to state what SineMacula does, then it looks like you should refactor that object an split concrete responsibilities to other objects.

HTH

Comment: The `SineMacula` object is much like jQuery or the jQuery UI in the sense that it is a library with many uses. So explaining what the `SineMacula` object does would probably take a paragraph or two, but so would explaining the jQuery UI. Correct?

Comment: I'm not well versed in jQuery, so I don't think I can comment on that; my main motivation is the OOP tag :). If you use SineMacula as a repository of methods then I guess it is not really an OO design; you are just using the idea of an object to group functions. If you want to go for a clean OO design you should identify the objects in your domain and assign responsibilities to them. While I can't speak without looking at the whole `SineMacula` object, it looks like `Form`, `Checkbox`, etc are good candidates to refactor `SineMacula`.

Comment: That is an interesting way to look at it, I originally just had functions such as `setCheckbox` etc, but decided I wanted to put all of these into a object/library, hence I created the `SineMacula` object. Maybe it would be better to keep them out of the object. I am quite new to OOP with Javascript so forgive my stupidity, but I got the idea of the jQuery UI. Have a look at one of the examples the following link and you will see why I have chosen to place these into an object. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I think that you are going in the right direction, it just takes some time :). Suppose that you have factored your `SineMacula` object into different objects, each one with its well defined responsibility. It may even happen that `SineMacula` becomes an empty object and thus you remove it. However it now may be tedious to create all those objects, so you create a new object (e.g. `FormCreator`) to help you with that process. Depending no how you define the responsibilities that `FormCreator` it may be some sort

Comment: of [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) or a [builder patern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that since you are housing all of your methods within this `SineMacula` namespace / module, there is no purpose in re-instantiating another whole new SineMacula object.

Unless you were going to be adding different / specific prototypes/methods that you **don't** want attached to the original object, and are specific to a certain section or form element on your page.

```
var newThing = new SineMacula('doDifferentStuff');
newThing.dropdown = '''do something different''';
```

The whole reason for instantiating the class would also be to set the new `this` to be whatever you are *invoking it from*. And it seems like everything you have is already tied in together, and simply uses the `SineMacula.setBlahblah` of calling itself.

Hope that doesn't sound too garbled!

Comment: If I wanted to call `newThing.dropdown.select(something)`, would it not be better to have an object. I wasn't aware that by creating an object like `new SineMacula.dropdown()` would create a whole new `SineMacula` object, I thought it would just create a new dropdown object

Comment: @BenCarey: Using `new SineMacula.dropdown()` doesn't create a new `SineMacula` object, it only creates a new `dropdown` object.